# How to copy Nuget package libraries to output folder with VS2015U2 and project.json?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, project.json

**What I have:**

- VS2015U2
- Class library project
- project.json

**What I need:** I need to copy only some(not all) of the Nuget references to the output folder.

*Note:* This could be easily done with the "CopyLocal" when using packages.config.

*Note2:* I found that I can use *CopyNuGetImplementations* in my .xproj file but this will copy all libraries which is not desired.

Comment: Can you set the reference property "Copy Local" to "false" on the references which you do not want to copy?

Comment: "Copy Local" option is no longer available in reference properties.

Comment: Hmmm, curious I have that option in VS 2015. I wonder what's different

Comment: So I've create a CL project. Added project.json. Added reference to Newtonsoft.Json. The properties widget of the nuget reference shows no properties at all.